# Delphi 2007, Indy 10 - What is the simplest TCP/IP setup for transferring a block of data in one direction

Tags: delphi, tcp, network-programming, delphi-2007, indy10

I have an application (the "server") which updates a block of data in memory - around 100k bytes - every second.

There are 1 to 4 other instances of a "client" application running on other workstations on the same network, and these need to read the same 100k image every second.

This has been implemented up til now by writing the image to a file on the server and having the clients read from that file across the network.  This has worked with no problems for many years, but lately (coincident with a move to windows 8-based hardware) it has developed a problem where the file becomes inaccessible to all nodes except one.  Exiting the client application running on this node frees up the file and it then becomes accessible again to everyone.

I'm still perplexed as to the the cause of this lockout, but I'm wondering if it may be the mechanism discussed [here](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=80148), where a file isn't closed due to a network glitch.  I'm thinking that having the clients request the data over TCP/IP would avoid this.

There doesn't need to be any handshaking other than the clients failing to connect or read data - the server just needs to go about it's business and respond to requests by grabbing the data and sending it.  I'm pretty hazy however about the best architecture to achieve this.  Are TidTCPClient and TidTCPServer going to cut it? I'm assuming the clients would request the data in a thread, but does this mean the server needs to run a thread continuously to respond to requests?

Comment: A small server side message push example for Indy can be found [here](https://mikejustin.wordpress.com/2014/04/19/indy-10-tidtcpserver-server-side-message-push-example/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TIdTCPServer` is a multi-threaded component.  Its clients run in worker threads that it manages for you.  All you have to do is implement the `OnExecute` event to send your data.

`TIdTCPClient` is not a multi-threaded component.  It runs in whatever thread you use it in.  So if you need to read data continuously, best to run your own worker thread to handle the reading.  Indy has a `TIdThreadComponent` component that wraps a thread, or you can write your own `TThread` code manually.

100K is not a lot of data, so I would suggest simply forgetting the file altogether and allocate a buffer in memory instead.  Your `TIdTCPServer.OnExecute` event handler can read from that buffer whenever needed.  And I wouldn't even bother having the clients request data, just have the server continuously push the latest data to active clients.

Try something like this:

---

server:

```
var
  Buffer: TIdBytes;
  Lock: TMREWSync;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  Lock.BeginRead;
  try
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(Buffer);
  finally
    Lock.EndRead;
  end;
  Sleep(1000);
end;

procedure TForm1.UpdateBuffer;
begin
  Lock.BeginWrite;
  try
    // update the Buffer content as needed...
  finally
    Lock.EndWrite;
  end;
end;

initialization
  Lock := TMREWSync.Create;
  SetLength(Buffer, 1024 * 100);
finalization
  SetLength(Buffer, 0);
  Lock.Free;
```

---

client:

```
procedure TForm1.IdThreadComponent1Run(Sender: TIdThreadComponent);
var
  Buffer: TIdBytes;
begin
  IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadBytes(Buffer, 1024 * 100);
  // use Buffer as needed...
end;

procedure TForm1.Connect;
begin
  IdTCPClient1.Connect;
  try
    IdThreadComponent1.Start;
  except
    IdTCPClient1.Disconnect;
    raise;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Disconnect;
begin
  IdTCPClient1.Disconnect;
  IdThreadComponent1.Stop;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Remy.  I don't follow how your server works - what triggers the OnExecute event - an incoming request from a client? I take it the `Sleep (1000)` is to pace the outgoing data at one lump per second, but what causes the event to retrigger?  I was planning on ditching the file and sending the stuff from memory and threading the server code, but from what you are saying I don't need to code a thread on the server - Indy does that already ?

Comment: @rossmcm the TIdTCPServer.OnExecute handler is called in a continuous loop for the duration of the connection, no specific event triggers it

Comment: @rossmcm: yes, `TIdTCPServer` creates a thread for each client that connects to it.  And mjn is correct, the `OnExecute` event is called in a continuous loop (within each client's thread) for the lifetime of the connection.

Comment: @Remy, This runs differently to how I thought things might work.  I imagined a thread would be created, do its work, and then destruct every second, on both the client and server PCs.  So my understanding now is: `1.` Client machine starts thread on application startup which connects to server.  `2.` Server starts thread as result of connection and serves a lump of data each second.  `3.` How does the client "take delivery" of the data that will presumably be available each second?  I understand that's what `ReadBytes` is for, but I'm unsure how it is paced when data is available regularly.

Comment: Creating a new thread, having it send/read one block of data, and then terminate, doing that every second for every client, is a waste of processing power and lots of overhead (threads are not cheap to create/destroy). If you look at the example I gave you, it uses the `TIdThreadComponent.OnRun` event, which works similar to the `TIdTCPServer.OnExecute` event. Basically, the client is also running a continuous loop for the lifetime of the connection, reading a block of data on each iteration. Indy uses blocking sockets, so `ReadBytes()` will block the calling thread until 100K has been read.

Comment: OK, I get it now.  I also need to request data from the server that will be a range of records from a disk file - i.e. the client will need to pass parameters, and the data will not be required regularly.  How would things need to change if I also needed to occasionally request stuff with parameters? (or should this be another question?  :-,)

Comment: You will have to design a command/response protocol, where each request asks for a particular type of data. The server can read a request and send the appropriate reply, read the next request and reply accordingly, and so on for the lifetime of the connection. Your data retrievals will be serialized as a client would only ask for one piece of data at a time, unless you design your protocol to be asynchronous so multiple requests can be in flight at the same time. But that gets more complicated to implement, on both sides. If you want details, then yes, ask a new question, with requirements.

Comment: You are very patient!  In the scenario for this question, there are likely to be several clients who will need the same data every second. Can I economise and only have the server send the data once, rather than N separate threads sending the same data to each client?

Comment: Not with TCP, no. Each client is distinct and independent.  As I showed you in my example, you can have a single source buffer, but you have to send a separate copy of its data to each individual client. The only way a server can perform 1 send that is received by N clients is to use UDP-based multicasting instead (such as with Indy's `TIdIPMCastClient` and `TIdIPMCastServer` components). Clients subscribe to the server's multicast group, and then the server can send 1 copy of data to the entire group as a whole.